# DevServer 17.0 - don't start the php 7.1.3 x.86

Tags: php

I running over Devserver 17.0 the PHP 5.6.30 x86 and apache 2.4.25 x86. but my processor is an x64. I want to change to PHP 7.1.3 x86 or whatever version PHP 7. the DevServer that I have been downloaded is PHP 7.1.3 x86 to select. but when I choose. The Apache doesn't start. the release of the DevServer 17 that I downloaded doesn't have module PHP 7 for x64.  Can be this my problem or the installed module of the PHP 7 is wrong in my Devserver? if that is the case where can I found the right package Php 7 to install in devserver 17.0 for x64?

Following below images from my DevServer scenery.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJEZy.png)

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58e11.png)

[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZB4T.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to \eds-binaries\httpserver\apachexxxx*\conf\, find **httpd-php.conf**, keep a backup for safety and then edit it and change the php5xxx paths to the php7xxx ones --check the proper folders to see what they are called.

- (whatever version of apache you have, navigate through windows to be sure)

If you have the PHP7 folder inside EasyPphp\eds-binaries\php\ and can't start the server after you've selected the php7 from the list you probably don't have the right **Visual C++ Redistributable**.

For PHP7 you need **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable**; you can find it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) (install both x64 and x86 versions).

Comment: Thank's RonS and marc_s. The Visual C++ Redistributable version that RonS recommended.  perfectly work!!! I had another version installed. Thank's!!!

Comment: Cheers! As it worked for you accept it as the answer and please give it an upvote.